# Server/client String[] array over Socket connection

Tags: java, database, sockets

I'm trying to send a String[] over an open socket connection but it's doesn't work.
I went to send an array from database and sending result set on client after a socket connection!

### Server

```
public class ServerConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

private static String String;
private Socket clientSocket;

public ServerConnectionHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}

public String[] toStringArray(ResultSet resultSet, String columnLabel) {
    LinkedList<String> resultList = new LinkedList<String>();
 
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            resultList.add(resultSet.getString(columnLabel));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 
    return resultList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
    
@Override
public void run() {

    
    

    ResultSet val = null;
    System.out.println("Client " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + clientSocket.getPort() + " has connected.");
    Mysql conn = new Mysql("****", "root", "","*****");
    val = conn.executeSelect(CONSTANT.QUERY_ALL);
    String[] mybytearray = toStringArray(val,"real_url");
    
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        
        String inputline, outputline;
        outputline = "Connected to server...type in the console to interact!";
        out.println(outputline);
        
        
        while((inputline = in.readLine()) != null){
            outputline = "Server echoes: " + mybytearray;
            out.println(outputline);
        }
    }
    
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Client " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + clientSocket.getPort() + " has disconnected.");
    }
    
}
```

}

### Client

```
public class ClientMain {

private String host;
private int port;

public ClientMain(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}

public void start() {
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        
        String inputline, outputline;
            while((inputline = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(inputline);
                outputline = getUserInput();
                out.println(outputline);
                
            }
    } 
    
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Server not running, shutting down...");
        System.exit(-1);
    } 
}

private static String getUserInput() {
    String s = "";
    InputStreamReader isr; 
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        s += br.readLine();
        
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    return s;
}
```

}

Comment: Please describe your inputs and the program's outputs in more detail.

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this code, not really sure where to start. Can we start with some more information on what exactly doesn't work, how does it manifest and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps that this code is not specific purpose it works quite well. I wish I could send data from a mysql request to customers! With this code I can not send the resultset to the client. I can send strings. I'd like to make this code better

Comment: if you have any advice :) i can to send all code if u prefer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the overall flawed design, I'm pretty sure this line is very wrong:

```
outputline = "Server echoes: " + mybytearray;
```

You're concatenating a string "Server echoes: " with an array. You can't do this.

Instead, try this:

```
outputline = "Server echoes: ";
for (String s : mybytearray) {
    outputline += s;
}
```

But why on earth you call array of String `mybytearray`?

*As a career advice consider using debugger facility available in every modern Java IDE.*

Comment: Thx u, yes it's work ! but in output client i have a data on single line.

Comment: Change to this, if you need new lines: 
`outputline += "\n" + s;`